# Whet's the difference between way to tell and way to say?

Tags: word-usage

What's the difference in meaning and intention between:

A) There's no way to say if she was poisoned.

and

B) There's no way to tell if she was poisoned.

Comment: @black-clover Please [edit your question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/553451/edit) to include what you found when you looked the words up in a dictionary or two. The community will help you understand what is unclear there; but we need to know what you already know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In usage, *announce, say, tell, report* forms a sequence of synonyms going from most direct to most indirect. When one *announces* something, the connotation is that the speaker speaks in person. When one *reports* something, it can be done via documents. There are exceptions, such as sending letters that announce the arrival of a baby, but even that carries the idea of some kind of herald.

The extremes of the sequence tend to be more literal, whereas the semantic range of *say* and *tell* includes ideas other than communication, ideas such as ‘knowing’. This is how your example comes across.

Between *say* and *tell*, “say” tends to be slightly more direct and literal. “I cannot say which I prefer” can refer to ambivalence, but context can also flip the meaning to “not allowed to mention it”. Switching to *tell* weights the sense more strongly towards ‘ambivalence’, although “cannot tell *you*” flips it other way.

The key is to determine whether say/tell is in the active voice or in what’s known as the ‘middle’ voice - are they ‘speaking’ to someone else, or are they ‘speaking’ to themselves?

In your example, both options are middle-voiced, and both mean “don’t know”. If you replace “if” with “whether”, though, it is possible to construe the “say” variant as “not allowed to tell you”.